# "1" gets switched to "\0"

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

We are having the oddest issue in our system, where "1" is get changed to "/0". Our application is services based. Wcf Web services. We call out to service A to get some data. That service calls service B which grabs the data and returns it. Service A simply maps that to a new object and returns it to the initial caller. I can call Service B directly and the data is fine, but coming through service A, if a certain string field is "1" it's coming back as "\0". This randomly started Thursday sometime. Code was definitely not updated, and nobody thinks there were any updated to the server these both run on.

here's code from service A. When the variable prog has CType of "1" the ProgramDTO returned by this method contains a CType of "\0"

```
 public ProgramDTO GetCProgram(string clId, int cType)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var clientChannel = (IClientChannel)cSpecsFactory.CreateChannel())
            {
                var client = (ICSpecs)clientChannel;
                var prog = client.GetCProgram(clId, cType);
                return ToDomainModel(prog);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Error getting programs.", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

  private ProgramDTO ToDomainModel(CProgramDTO c)
    {
        try
        {
            return new ProgramDTO
                    {
                        CType = c.CType,
                        ClID = c.ClId,
                        IsET = c.IsET,
                        PreviewImage = c.Image,
                        CId = c.CId,

                    };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(string.Format("Error converting to domain model."), ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

public class ProgramDTO
{

    [DataMember]
    public string ClID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsET { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public byte[] PreviewImage { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long CId { get; set; }


}
```

The only thing that i can think of that is different is when service B gets this data, it's an int and it we convert to a string.

```
CType = cProgram.CType.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

We don't use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture anywhere else, but nothing else(atleast 6, 50 and 51 are ok) is having problems, and when it returns from this services it still looks ok.

Comment: Can you show the relevant ProgramDTO constructor?

Comment: no constructor. I updated the original post to contain the class.

Comment: What does `GetCProgram()` do?

Comment: That is Service B that I reference. it just gets data from the database and returns it in a CProgramDTO. The value is still intact when it comes back from this service.

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't be catching exceptions in every method. In particular, there should be no try/catch in the private methods like `ToDomainModel`. Without the try/catch there, the exception will propagate up to the caller, where it will be caught and logged. The stack trace will show that the exception originated in `ToDomainModel`, so you don't need logging to say that.

Comment: yeah, apparently we went a bit log happy... and it's still missing in key places of course.

Comment: It's pretty rare for things to just stop working for no reason. *Something* changed. You need to put a debugger on Service A and trace the data path, examining the data as you go.

Comment: I know, but I can't debug in production. I haven't been able to reproduce the error elsewhere. The application wouldn't have been updated, I don't know what kind of server updates that would cause something like this. No windows updates for months. The ops team that takes care of the servers aren't aware of any changes. This is probably the strangest one I've seen.

Comment: \0 is the ascii code for NULL. Is it possible that the ProgramDTO you get is NULL and thus every member variables is hold also get a value of NULL like you get? It could happens because your services uses other languages that don't work well with .net NULL and hence send back their own version of NULL. Do you get \0 on the other member variables too?

Comment: Nope just the that one, and only when the value should be "1". None of the others have "1" as a value though. Also, both services are written in c#